# Wordpress URL rewrite after changing web from Joomla

Tags: rewrite-rules

There is a website which was previously run on Joomla. URL structure of Joomla links was index.php/site , index.php/another-site. After changing to WordPress no page is not accessible from Google, I get just white pages saying No input file specified. I guess I need some .htaccess rewrite at least to redirect to homepage? I needed to also redirect all links to a new ones, but I was not successful so far. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Basic WP .htaccess rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) it should at least be taking you to /site and /anothersite on the WordPress install and driving a 404. However it appears your server is handling 404 errors without passing them to WordPress. You may be able to add a custom php5.ini file with the directive `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1`. Alternatively adding this to the top of your .htaccess file could disable FastCGI

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
```